# Why for only some actions must I call setTarget?

Tags: cocoa, action, nstableview, target

For most actions, I just click and drag in InterfaceBuilder to "wire up" a call from some interface object to my code. For example, if I want to know when the user single-clicks a row in a table, I drag a connection from the table's action to my controller's action.

But now let's consider the user double-clicking a row. If I want one of my actions to be called when this happens, I need to call not only `-[NSTableView setDoubleAction]` but **also** `-[NSControl setTarget]`. Why?

To be clear, I am **not** asking why Interface Builder doesn't support `setDoubleAction`. All tools have limitations. I am trying to gain a greater understanding about how and why `setTarget` doesn't seem to be necessary unless and until I want `setDoubleAction` to work. Another way to ask this question would be: Why don't I need to do anything in Interface Builder to set the target of the table's (single-click) action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you connect your table view to an action in IB, then call `setDoubleAction` on it, there should be no need to make an additional call to `setTarget`. However, if you only wish to receive the double click message, and you didn’t connect the table view to an action in IB, you *will* have to call `setTarget`.

A table view will send `action` and `doubleAction` to the same target. You can imagine NSTableView as being implemented like this:

```
@implementation NSTableView

- (void)theUserClickedOnMe
{
   [self sendAction:[self action] to:[self target];
}

- (void)theUserDoubleClickedOnMe
{
   [self sendAction:[self doubleAction] to:[self target]];
}

@end
```

And what you’re doing in IB is something like this:

```
- (void)userConnectedControl:(NSControl *)control
        toAction:(SEL)action
        ofObject:(id)object
{
   [control setTarget:object];
   [control setAction:action];
}
```

The real implementations are nowhere close to that, but that is effectively what’s going on.

Answer (score 1):

If you set an action (or double-click action) and don't set a target (or set the target to `nil`), then the action message will go through the responder chain.

If you set a target in addition to an action, the action message will go only to that object.